# how to print the return value of a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to print the return value from a function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click').click(function (e) {
        var value = 1;
        check(value); //function call with value:value=1
        alert(val); //here i want to return the value from function
    });
    function check(value) {
        if (value == 1) {
            var val = 'success';
            return val;
        } else {
            var val = 'error';
        }
    }
}); //document ready function
```

so how to acieve the return value of the function and print the value of the function which was returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this:

```
var value = 1;
var valofvalue = check(value); //function call with value:value=1
alert(valofvalue); //here i want to return the value from function
```

Or, even shorter:

```
var value = 1;
alert(check(value));
```

The reason it wasn't working is because `val` is not a global variable - it was made only in the `check()` function and no one other than the things inside `check()` can access it. So I made another variable, `valofvalue`, to store the return value and use it in the `click` function.

Even better, to save making multiple variables, put the `val` variable all the way at the top of the function, so you don't need to return anything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var val = ''; 

  $('.click').click(function (e) {
    var value = 1;
    check(value); 
    alert(val);
  });

  function check(value) {
    if (value == 1) {
        val = 'success';
    } else {
        val = 'error';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you @TheJuniorProgrammer but if i remove global variable var val=''; and remain all code as usuall still it returns the val.

Comment: Really? Interesting! If my code worked, please accept and upvote, if you can!